# How to run a function on Server-side on a Button Click event which won't affect postback of Page (ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net

I have a Button-click event on my Code-behind which uploads some data from an excel sheet to database. This upload triggers another function which does some maintenance activities over the uploaded data on the database.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some excel upload code
    Recon.Start(); //Maintanance Task. Takes atleast 20s to execute.
}
```

Now the problem is until this `Recon.Start()` function completes, the postback doesn't happen and the page keeps loading on client-side. I want to make the page-load independent of this last function i.e. `Recon.Start()`

Can you tell me the possible ways?

**UPDATE :**

After some research, I found that an `Windows Service` could do the job more efficiently. I need to isolate and separate the `Recon.Start()` code as an windows service and need to call or trigger this from my `Button_Click` event.

Comment: You can send an asyn ajax call in javascript submit of file upload using the jQuery and web method.

Comment: @Chandan Roy..The post back happens as soon as button click is trigerred. It is the Recon.Start() func which is taking time to complete there by pausing completion of Postback. You have to look at optimizing your Recon.Start() to make it faster

Comment: If the async request is triggered then the page should not keep loading. Are you using PageMethods?

Comment: Bottleneck is in any case, I can't reduce the execution time of `Recon.Start()`. Moreover, I cant handle that function from client-side as this is a maintenance job and requirements wants me to completely hide it at server-side. It is like client won't know anything is happening on server-side (i.e. No waiting time).